# How to find from what computer I connected to a current server

Tags: ssh, users

I often work on one of available to me Linux/HP-UX servers (let's say it is server1) and then do  `ssh server2` ((let's say it is server2)) and start working on another Linux/HP-UX server. Then I can connect another server ((let's say it is server3) and start working on it. While working on server3 how to get in command line information from what server I came from?

So on server3 I want to get information that I came from server2 and on server2 I want to get information that I came from server1? What is a command or utility for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for Linux, `who <arg> <arg>` will display the host you connected from.

```
$ who hates java
error    pts/3        2013-11-20 08:35 (underground)
```

The HP/UX man pages indicate the same is true for that operating system. As it should be; I've been using this for decades on a variety of Unixes...

Answer (score 2):

Ssh always sets upon a successful connection several [environment variables](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#ENVIRONMENT), including:

> [`SSH_CONNECTION`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#SSH_CONNECTION)
>
> Identifies the client and server ends of the connection. The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

This is an example:

```
$ ssh user@host
user@host$ echo $SSH_CONNECTION
192.168.223.17 36673 192.168.223.229 22
```

So it is possible to get this environment variable and then `nslookup` to get information about a host from which the connection was done:

```
user@host$ nslookup "${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}"'
...
Name:      192.168.223.17
Address 1: 192.168.223.17 foo.bar
```

Unless `who(1)` this also work from a non-interactive ssh command, and does not rely on the defective/unreliable utmp mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

`who` , `whoami` and `last` come to mind but no HPUX athand to test

Comment: Just to notice: `who am i`, not `whoami`