# In a remote shell, how can I find out from which computer I logged into the remote machine?

Tags: ssh, remote, hostname

In a remote shell, how can I find the domain name of the computer from which I logged into the remote machine?

Example: My local machine is `mi.pona.com`. On this machine I run

```
ssh toki@sina.pona.com
```

to login into the remote machine `sina.pona.com`. In the shell  which opens (running on the remote machine) I want to find out from which computer I logged in, so I want to get the result "**mi.pona.com**". Is there a command for this?

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/244520/5132 , https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101955/5132 , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322227/5132 .

Comment: @user431397 ??? They all have pretty much the same answers mentioning `whoami` and `SSH_CONNECTION`. On https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101955/how-to-find-from-what-computer-i-connected-to-a-current-server the top answer only mentions `who`, but you can fix that by voting for the better answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my Red Hat 7 machine, I run `who am i` or `who am I` or `who -m`.
The last column will show the machine name where I logged in from (in parenthesis). If I am on my local machine, the last column will show my console/display ID. On my machine it is (:0).

**Caveat**
This only works on an interactive shell.
`ssh ScottieH@RemoteServer who -m` will give unexpected results.
On my Red Hat 7 machine, It spews an error.
YMMV

Comment: `who am i` doesn't work. `who am I` doesn't work. `who -m` returns the same as `who`. and why not just use `w`?

Comment: what about `whoami` ?

Comment: @AaronF `w` doesn't show me the address, but `w -f` does. `who am i` is showing me the same output as `who` and `who -m`. The manpage says "If ARG1 ARG2 given, -m presumed: 'am i' or 'mom likes' are usual." That seems to indicate that `who am i` should always be the same as `who -m`. This is GNU's `who` v8.31.

Comment: @JoL "who am i is showing me the same output as who and who -m" - in which case I take back what I said. I just found a RHEL7 box and tried it and it works. Not sure why it doesn't on my local Manjaro installation, even though my manual for `who` says "If given two non-option arguments, ‘who’ prints only the entry for
the user running it (determined from its standard input), preceded by
the hostname.  Traditionally, the two arguments given are ‘am i’, as in
‘who am i’". Also, strangely enough, `w` shows addresses on RHEL but doesn't on Manjaro (I've never tried running `w` locally before).

Comment: `whoami` vs `who am i` vs `who -m`, etc. is OS (Flavor, version & perhaps platform) dependent. Tjat is why I specified all of the programs that I know work on my machine -- and specified the OS version. Also note the YMMV caveat: Your Mileage May Vary). The last OS I used that had `w` was actually an alias to who -m. Not every one has access to the `last` database.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `w`, `who` or even `last`.

Also you can check `sshd` logs, `journalctl -u sshd -n 100`